# CSS Background Transition & Responsive (fade)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fadein, transition

A member of this forum was kind enough to provide the following CSS rollover code which is "fluid" and can adjust in dimensions based on browser size. I've included the code below along with Jfiddle link:

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
a.widgetbook {
    display:block;
    max-width: 369px;
    max-height: 85px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://69.195.124.70/~profetz4/wp-content/themes/artificer/images/btn-contact.jpg") no-repeat left top;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-size: 200%;
}
a.widgetbook:hover {
    background-position: right top;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="widgetbook">
</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cw6hN/

I'm looking to apply a fade-in CSS transition that will position the rollover image properly, and then fade in with an opacity of 1. I'm able to do this to a standard button (non-responsive) but haven't figured out how to apply it to the button scenario above. Any help on how to best achieve this would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

D

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: Hi DropOut, no Jquery in this case. Just pure css

Answer (score 2):

Updated JSFiddle to how you wanted it, but using 2 separate images.

Add this to `a.widgetbook`

`transition:all .6s;`

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/TAA6J/)

To get the 'fade in' affect you're looking for, you'll need to create two different images.

Comment: Hey BeatAlex, Thanks for the response. It seems as though your Jsfiddle example doesn't allow for the resizing of the button. I actually found some code out here on the forums and combined it into this. It works as far as I can tell and it uses a single image to boot. I'd still be interested in hearing any thoughts from the rest of the community about what I came up with. http://jsfiddle.net/cw6hN/1/

Comment: @user2325396 That works perfectly (Your jsfiddle), if I were you I'd go with that! Clean, uses CSS only and works perfectly! :)